# How to make AsyncCompletedEventArgs Serializable

Tags: c#, wcf, serialization, httprequest, httpresponse

Is there a workaround to make AsyncCompletedEventArgs class serializable?

Here's an example of what I'm trying to do:

I have a service reference that contains : `FooCompletedEventArgs receivedObject`

Then:

```
public JsonResult Foo(FooCompletedEventArgs fooObject)
{
    return new JsonResult() { Data = fooObject, MaxJsonLength = int.MaxValue };
}
```

And in the other side I do:

```
public void FooFoo(FooCompletedEventArgs receivedFooObject)
{
    FooCompletedEventArgs model = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<FooCompletedEventArgs>(e);
}
```

It fails when I want to deserialize it.

I checked the generated service reference, and I noticed that all the attributes only have get functions not set.